# How to create a two div one fixed size and another 100%

Tags: css, html

I want create two DIV. Left DIV has a background with image. The size of this image is always 100% of DIV. So if I change resolution I have image in small size. In the right I have another div with fixed width.

**HTML Code**

```
<div id="left">Test1</div>
<div id="right">Test</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

**CSS Code**

```
#left{
    float: left;
    background: url('http://www.dladziecibajki.com/tapety/21790373a4e876e9dfe1d3949a2d5345_1344597749.jpg') 0 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
#right{
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

This is my code: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U47r5/3/)

Kind regards

Answer (score 1):

### [Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/swfour/U47r5/4/)

HTML

```
<div id="right">Test</div>
<div id="left">Test1</div>
```

CSS

```
#left {
    background: url('http://www.dladziecibajki.com/tapety/21790373a4e876e9dfe1d3949a2d5345_1344597749.jpg') 0 0;
    height: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}
#right {
    float: left;
    width: 380px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: But how to display image in full resolution ? even text is not long ?

Comment: @user3531797 - please provide an example of your deisred output

Comment: Here you are: http://www.pizzasaluto.pl/ I want fixed image like this but on the right site DIV which is next t this image.

Comment: Background image. It's resize with web browser and I want do the same but on the right site i want create DIV with fixed width. Of course with out cut background. Now you understand ?